# Find real numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that $ad-bc=1$ and $f\left(z\right)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ for any $z\in\mathbb{H}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

For $z\in\mathbb{H}$, define $$f\left(z\right)=\frac{z-1}{3z+1}.$$

(a) Prove that $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{H}$. (Done)

(b) Find real numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that $ad-bc=1$ and $f\left(z\right)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ for any $z\in\mathbb{H}$.

$ad-bc=1$  is the deteminants of the special linear group $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. But can we find those specific real numbers?

Comment: This is not clear.  Is there some other definition of $f(z)$?  How do you know if you have found the right $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: I edited to include the whole problem. I am done with (a).

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if

$$f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d},$$

then for any $t\neq 0$ we have

$$f(z) = \frac{t(az+b)}{t(cz+d)}=\frac{taz+tb}{tcz+td}.$$

Now, the effect of multiplication by $t$ on the coefficient calculation $ad-bc$ results in $t^2(ad-bc)$.
We can hence reverse engineer our problem.

The given $f$ has $ad-bc = 1\times 1 - (-1)\times 3= 1+3 = 4$.
To reach $1$, we must multiply it by $t^2 = \frac14$, so you can choose either of $t=\pm \frac12$.